# Electrolyte capacitor polarization

Tags: capacitance, polarization, dielectric

The anode of the electrolyte capacitor is an aluminum with an aluminum oxide. The cathode is also aluminum separated by electrolyte liquid.

As far as I understand the dielectric is formed at the anode size with the aluminum oxide.
Can someone give me physics explanation why the formation of the dielectric material is polarized such that if one is applying reverse the capacitor is damaged?

I am not a physicist but somehow it reminds me the Schottky diode (metal-n junction) where applying one direction electric field causing current and reverse is non conducting current.